# How to iterate through 2 zipped list of dictionaries under certain conditions?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, zip

There are 4 list of dictionaries, the first two need to be added to the database, the second 2 already exist in the database:

```
to_add1 = [{'name': 'Kate', 'age': 25, 'id': 1234},
           {'name': 'Claire', 'age': 25, 'id': 4567},
           {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'id': 8910}]

to_add2 = [{'pets': 5, 'name_id': 1234},
           {'pets': 0, 'name_id': 4567},
           {'pets': 0, 'name_id': 8910}]

existing1 = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 50, 'id': 0000},
             {'name': 'Claire', 'age': 25, 'id': 4567}]
existing2 = [{'pets': 2, 'name_id': 0000},
             {'pets': 0, 'name_id': 4567}]
```

I would like to add to the database or in this reproducible example, print only the items that do not contain the `existing1['name']` value in `existing1`. So in this case: Kate and Bob from `to_add1` should be printed once. Due to the double loop, I am getting repetitions.  How can I loop through all these dictionaries and print the items that do have a matching name to the names of`existing 1` without repetitions ?

My code:

```
for person_to_add, pet_to_add in zip(to_add1, to_add2):
    for existing_person, existing_pet in zip(existing1, existing2):
        if person_to_add['name'] not in existing_person['name']:
            print(person_to_add)
```

Current output:

```
{'name': 'Kate', 'age': 25, 'id': 1234}
{'name': 'Kate', 'age': 25, 'id': 1234}
{'name': 'Claire', 'age': 25, 'id': 4567}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'id': 8910}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'id': 8910}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{'name': 'Kate', 'age': 25, 'id': 4567}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'id': 8910}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the actual underlying query this might not work. But here is a solution taking advantage of the list of dictionary structure you are using. It is unclear exactly to me why you would need to use zip.

```
a = [person_to_add for person_to_add in to_add1 if person_to_add['name'] not in [existing_person['name'] for existing_person in existing1]]
```

This uses list comprehensions which should be pretty fast. The output 'a' would be in the same format as all your other data i.e a list of dicts. Do let me know if you need a further breakdown on how the list comprehension works.

Comment: your answer is the closest so far as I am specifically in need of checking the dictionary value of ['name'], whether those match - hence why I had initially made those 2 loops.  Your result is a list; a next step to this would be to iterate again through 'a', so that I can add each dictionary one by one to the database (using Solr with Pysolr). Basically, if the name exists in Solr, dont add the dictionary else, add the dictionary.

Comment: OK, i think I figured it out. What I wanted was this: ```a = [[person_to_add, pet_to_add] for person_to_add, pet_to_add in zip(to_add1, to_add2) if person_to_add['name'] not in [existing_person['name'], for existing_person in existing1]]```

Comment: Looks good to me. Although I would say that you have to be careful with zip, it might be doing something you are not expecting. Note that if your list is not in the same order you get entirely different results.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the output should be `Kate` & `Bob` because `Claire` is in `existing1`:

```
>>> for person_to_add, pet_to_add in zip(to_add1, to_add2):
...     if person_to_add not in existing1:
...         print(person_to_add)
... 
{'name': 'Kate', 'age': 25, 'id': 1234}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'id': 8910}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [print(person_to_add) for person_to_add in to_add1 if person_to_add not in existing1]
```

It might not the fastest solution but it get the job done. it uses python list comprehension, and easy to read.

As you described in the problem that you  only want to compare data in existing1 and to_add1 so you don't need use nested loops adding unnecessary complexity. you will be fine using a single loop.

Comment: I am specifically looking at whether the 'name' value matches, not if the whole dictionary item matches - don't you need to a second loop to loop over that ['name'] value ?

Comment: I appreciate you for point it out, i kind of missed the ['name'] , so here is the updated version which takes only name into compassion and don't use another loop.
```lst = [print(person_to_add) for person_to_add in to_add1 if person_to_add['name'] not in map(lambda d: d['name'], existing1)]
```